# Number of ways to send presents to coworkers

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Imagine that you have a warehouse full of 6 different types presents. You want to send 1 or 2 presents to each of 10 different coworkers. How many different ways are there to do this?

Remark: If one of the coworkers gets two presents, they must be different.

Is it correct to think of this situation as distributing 10 identical presents to 6 different types?

This would imply: $${n + k-1 \choose k-1} = {10 + 6-1 \choose 6-1} = {15 \choose 5}$$

I feel that this is incorrect because I don't think that this assures that each individual gets a minimum of 1 present. It would be great if someone could explain the logic of this problem to me. Thank you.

Comment: This doesnt take into account those who get two... I guess.

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding the question.  Just consider the case where every employee gets $2$.  There are $\frac {6\times 5}2=15$ ways to choose a pair of presents and I get one such choice for each employee...thus this case contributes $15^{10}=576650390625$.  Whereas $\binom {15}5 = 3003$.  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Even the case wherein each employee gets exactly $1$ present contributes $6^{10}=60466176$.

Comment: @lulu I think that you are correct. Your stating that there is $6 \choose 2$ ways to pick $2$ presents from $6$ for the first person, and the same for all the rest which does imply $15^{10}$ because these choices are successive with replacement? But now what I don't understand is what if now they can recieve one OR two presents?

Comment: The posted solution from @user2277550 handles it correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 different presents can be chosen in $ 6 \choose 2$ ways. 1 can be chosen in $6\choose1$ ways.

So the final answer would be $$ \left({6 \choose 2} + {6 \choose 1}\right)^{10} $$

This takes care of all the cases I guess.

Comment: Note:  I took the liberty of making your parentheses larger, please undo what I did if you prefer it otherwise.  (+1) for the full solution.